# How to build the NHibernate Sharding project?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, build

it may sound stupid but since I've never done such things before, I'm not able to build the NHibernate Sharding project. Look at this [trunk](http://nhcontrib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nhcontrib/trunk/), the documentation folder is empty (oh no) and in the src directory, there are several components of the project including an ominous default.build file.

What do I have to do? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the tar-ed code from the link [Download GNU tarball](http://nhcontrib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nhcontrib/trunk/src/?view=tar) at the bottom of the link that you give. Extracted the src\NHibernate.Shards\ folder and built the NHibernate.Shards.sln. Worked!

Maybe you did not download the lib directory that is in the src\NHibernate.Shards\ folder? There are references to dll's there.